# Method keyword argument is same in every call

Tags: python

I have following method

```
>>> import uuid
>>> def get_sample(sample_value=str(uuid.uuid4())):
...     return sample_value
...
>>> print(get_sample())
2ca4a40c-62c4-4efa-add4-8f13067349d5
>>> print(get_sample())
2ca4a40c-62c4-4efa-add4-8f13067349d5
>>> print(get_sample())
2ca4a40c-62c4-4efa-add4-8f13067349d5
>>> print(get_sample())
2ca4a40c-62c4-4efa-add4-8f13067349d5
```

Every invocation of the method returns same value.

Want to understand what's happening here. Can this be modified to return new UUID in every call?

Comment: `uuid.uuid4()` is evaluated once when the function is defined, providing a static default arg value, not each time the function is called

Comment: @matszwecja the answers to that question explain why this is broken though